# Create table-like columns where each column is a descendant of its adjacent column

Tags: html

I would like to create 3 columns. The first column on the left acts like a parent at the root level. The second column is a child of the first column and third column is a child of the second column.

Creating tables with columns is pretty standard but all the solutions I am aware of have the columns as siblings. I would like to have them as a hierarchy instead. This is useful in a React app where content in a descendent is dependent upon its parent.

Is it possible to achieve this in html? Visually the columns look no different than they do in any other table. The closest I've come is this:

```
<div id="column1">
   <div style="width:300px">
      Column 1
   </div>
   <div id="column2" style="float: right;">
      Column 2
      <div id="column3" style="float:right; width:300px;">
         Column 3
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

NOTE: The table only has one row. The first and third column have a fixed width while the second column can be adjustable with the browser window size. In my code above, the content in column one looks like it's a sibling of column 2. It isn't. The first div is column 1. I only added a div around the content of column 1 to later on adjust the content in column one.

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out:

```
<div id="column1" style=" display: flex;">
  <div style="width:300px;">
    Column 1
  </div>
  <div id="column2" style="flex-grow: 1;display: flex;">
    <div style="flex-grow: 1;">Column 2</div>
    <div id="column3" style="width: 300px;">
      Column 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```